# How to create a function to subtract to another table field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the table items, which has the field "Quantity". So when i sell one or more items correspondent to any given ID, I want to subtract the quantity I just sold to that ID..

so far I've tried this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_subtract (
      @QTY int,
      @Item_ID int
) 
RETURNS VOID

AS 
    UPDATE Items
    SET Quantity = (SELECT Quantity - @QTY 
                    FROM Items 
                    WHERE @Item_ID = Item_ID
                   )
    WHERE @Item_ID =Item_ID
```

but it throws me an error nears the UPDATE keyword.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use a stored procedure for this.

Comment: alright :P thanks, ill use sp

Comment: `update` is not allowed in UDFs.  I believe you are looking for a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is the error?

Functions should not manipulate. Bad style. a SP yes, but not a function.

And ou do not know you can combine select and update into 1?

Update items SET QUantity = Quantity - @QTY WHERE ....

would also work and be simpler.